# Replace all Non-Alphanumeric Characters except one particular pattern using RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose, I have some text like

**text = "xyz - aabc 123.56 cancer s15.2 date 12/03/2021 @ dd hospital www.someurl ocr.5rror 123.sometext"**

Now, I want to create a regex that will replace any non-alphanumeric character with space except the dot(.) surrounded by digit, that is the final text should be like this

**"xyz aabc 123.56 cancer s15.2 date 12 03 2021 dd hospital www someurl ocr 5rror 123 sometext"**

I have this regex that can find these matches
*re.findall(r"(\b[a-z0-9]*\d.\d[a-z0-9]*\b)", text)* gives me *['123.56', 's15.2']*,
but I am not able to get the above text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use re.sub and a pattern with a capture group

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+))|\W+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+))` Capture digits with an optional decimal part with a dot in **group 1**
- `|` OR
- `\W+` Match 1+ non word characters to replace with a single space (or use a negated character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` to keep matching an underscore)

In the replacement keep the capture group, and replace the match for 1+ non word characters with a space.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS7Kvk/1/) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SPrJbs)

```
import re

s = "xyz - aabc 123.56 cancer s15.2 date 12/03/2021 @ dd hospital www.someurl ocr.5rror 123.sometext"
pattern = r"(\d+(?:\.\d+))|\W+"
print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else " ", s))
```

Output

```
xyz aabc 123.56 cancer s15.2 date 12 03 2021 dd hospital www someurl ocr 5rror 123 sometext
```